# How are complex fields in Azure Search represented in a database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-cognitive-search

When using Azure Cognitive Search, you can push complex fields to the index with JSON, like so (using a simplified version of the official Hotels example):

```
{
      "HotelId": "1",
      "HotelName": "Secret Point Hotel",
      "Category": "Boutique",
      "Tags": [ "view", "air conditioning", "concierge" ],
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
        "City": "New York",
        "StateProvince": "NY",
        "PostalCode": "10022",
        "Country": "USA"
      },
      "Rooms": [
        {
          "Description": "Budget Room, 1 Queen Bed (Cityside)",
          "Description_fr": "Chambre Économique, 1 grand lit (côté ville)",
          "Type": "Budget Room",
          "BaseRate": 96.99,
          "BedOptions": "1 Queen Bed",
          "SleepsCount": 2,
          "SmokingAllowed": true,
          "Tags": [ "vcr/dvd" ]
        },
        {
          "Description": "Budget Room, 1 King Bed (Mountain View)",
          "Description_fr": "Chambre Économique, 1 très grand lit (Mountain View)",
          "Type": "Budget Room",
          "BaseRate": 80.99,
          "BedOptions": "1 King Bed",
          "SleepsCount": 2,
          "SmokingAllowed": true,
          "Tags": [ "vcr/dvd", "jacuzzi tub" ]
        },
     ]
}
```

Notice how there are a couple complex field types here, Tags, Address, and Rooms. Since Rooms is the most difficult of the three, let's model out Rooms. The official SQL scripts do not include any sort of data creation for rooms, so I can't see how an indexer might find/read that data.

How do I need to represent my data (in the view that the indexer is reading from) in order to create a complex collection such as the `Rooms` example above?

If that's not possible, is it even possible to represent `Address` in the database in a way that it could be transferred to Azure Search in the schema below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a Data Source that is attached to a SQL view that contains all of your Hotel data. Your view should have columns (Tags, Address, Rooms) that contain embedded JSON which represent the complex types.

This is an example of creating a view with a 'Rooms' column that will contain data from the Rooms table:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[HotelRooms]
AS
SELECT *, (SELECT *
         FROM dbo.Rooms
         WHERE dbo.Rooms.HotelID = dbo.Hotels.HotelID FOR JSON AUTO) AS Rooms
FROM dbo.Hotels
GO
```

This view will have a column `Room` which will be populated with a JSON array eg: `[{"Description": "Budget Room"},{"Description": "Another Room"}]`

The columns listed on your view should match exactly with your Index schema. You will need to create a field on your Index called `Room` of type `Collection(Edm.ComplexType)` which will contain child fields such as `Description`.

For more information please see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-sql-relational-data